# GERAR UM SELECT DENTRO DE UMA PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Boa noite pessoal,

Estou tentando fazer um select dentro de uma procedure no ORACLE, só que não estou conseguindo gerar. Segue abaixo um exemplo de código que estou tentando gerar.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TRAZNOMES IS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM EMP;
END;
/
```

Fico muito agradecido, caso possam tentar me ajudar.

Atenciosamente.

Comment: O que você pretende fazer com esse select? Pegar um valor específico, efetuar um loop no mesmo?

Comment: Pretendo ler todos os campos que existem nessa tabela.

Comment: Todos os campos e registros?

Comment: Os campos existentes na tabela são EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO

Comment: Isso mesmo, todos os campos e registros.

Comment: Existem muitos tutoriais introdutórios sobre plsql , leia um deles , me parece que vocêuma FUNCTION , dica um "select" em pl-sql precisa retornar uma e apenas linha, do contrário use cursores. Este me parece bom https://www.docsity.com/pt/programando-prodedualmente-em-pl-sql/4733270/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você precisa fazer um `select` dentro de uma `procedure` e efetuar um loop no mesmo, normalmente trabalha-se com um `cursor`, sendo que o mesmo precisa ser declarado dentro de sua `procedure`, veja um exemplo utilizando sua `procedure` e `select`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TRAZNOMES IS
    CURSOR C_EMP IS
        SELECT * FROM EMP;
BEGIN
   FOR XEMP in C_EMP LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(XEMP.ENAME);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Esse exemplo o cursor é aberto com uma sintaxe semelhante a um foreach, a variável `XEMP` se torna o objeto para acessar os campos do cursor.

Comment: Muitíssimo agradecido pela explicação. Vou dar uma olhada melhor, sobre como trabalhar com um cursor.